# Quick way to get all of the items in a select list as an array of strings?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I have a page with a select list that contains a very large number of items.

I want to get all the items it contains (as String objects) and stick them into an Array.

Select#options returns an OptionsCollection, which means the best I've been able to come up with so far is this:

`text_array = my_huge_select_list.options.map { |opt| opt.text }`

...but, WOW, is that ever slow!

Is there some faster way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a select list with 450 options, manually parsing the html reduced the time from 113 seconds (while using Watir to map the option text) to 16 seconds.

This was done with the following command:

```
text_array = browser.select_list.html.scan(/<option[^>]*?>(.*?)<\/option>/i).flatten
```

A couple of things to note about the regex:

- The `[^>]*?` in the opening option tag is used to handle any attributes on the element. It could be omitted if you know there are none.
- The regex is made case-insensitive by the `i` parameter. In Firefox and Chrome, the elements in the html will be lowercase. However, IE capitalizes them.

Risks:

- Assumes that the option only includes text. While it would work if there are html elements in the options, it would take more manual parsing.
- Assumes that your options have closing tags. I believe IE does not automatically add closing tags if they are missing. If you do not have closing tags, you may need to modify the regex.

It is not pretty, but it does seem to be faster than collecting the text through Watir's option collection. However, it is not faster than Nokogiri, which was 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, this isn't bench-marked (and I'm curious how many options there are in that select list), but you could potentially use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).

Here's a contrived select list.  First, the options in the select list are obtained via the `css` method.  Then, the text for each option is added to the `text_array` array.  At that point, `text_array` is an array of strings.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML <<DOC
<select id="list">
  <option value="AL">AL</option>
  <option value="AK">AK</option>
  <option value="AS">AS</option>
  <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
<select>
DOC

options = doc.css("select option")
text_array = []
options.each { |opt| text_array << opt.text}

text_array[0]
# =>  AL
text_array[0].class
# =>  String
```

Comment: The list is 450 items long. I'd accept your answer, except that I'm not currently using Nokogiri in the project and hesitate to add the gem to it in order to do this one thing.